# registerType exception using autofac in netcore

Tags: c#, .net-core, autofac

This is not an issue, but a question. I have the following sample code:

```
class CommonArgs{
}

class TestArgs : CommonArgs{
}

abstract class AbstractHandler where T: CommonArgs, new (){
}

class TestHandler: AbstractHandler{
}
```

I use autofac to register the type:

```
builder.RegisterType (typeof (TestHandler)). Named ("testHandler", typeof (AbstractHandler<>)). InstancePerLifetimeScope ();
```

When I `build.Build ()`, I get an exception:

> System.ArgumentException: "The type 'TestHandler' is not assignable to service 'testHandler (AbstractHandler`1)'."

What is the correct type of registration? （use dotnet core Autofac 4.8.1）

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then [edit] your question to include the source code you have as a [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others. Why are you using `AbstractHandler<>` when you class doesn't have generics?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were almost there, just use the `RegisterType` overload and a `Named` with some string key and a `typeof(AbstractHandler<CommonArgs>))`

Here is a [link](https://github.com/ShaharShokrani/DependencyInjectionAutofac/blob/master/Section2%20-%20Registrations%20Concepts/RegisteringAnAbstractGenericClass.cs) to my github with a small unit-test to issue your question.

Code:

```
ContainerBuilder builder = new ContainerBuilder();            
builder.RegisterType<TestHandler>().Named("myTestHandler", typeof(AbstractHandler<CommonArgs>));

IContainer container = builder.Build();

var testHandler = container.ResolveNamed("myTestHandler", typeof(AbstractHandler<CommonArgs>));
```

Comment: my TestHandler is like this:
class TestHandler: AbstractHandler<TestArgs>{
}

I want to registerType with named，because I only know the name in the scene where I resolve the object

Comment: Hey @stonezhu I've updated my answer, (also the code in the link)